# How to specify an onclick parameter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a tough time using jQuery to give a button the ability to delete it's own row. Specifically, I the selection process find extremely confusing.

The table has an id of `foo` and the button has a class of `'delete`. Shouldn't the following code select the button?  It's just the `****.on('click', function(event){})` part that I am struggling to understand. I just want the button created to be selected to have the `on` response.

```js
$('#foo tr:last').after(`<tr id="1"><td>fname</td>
   <td>lname</td>
   <td>pnumber</td>
   <td>address</td>
   <td><button class="delete" id="1" type="click">Delete</button></td>`)


$("#foo .delete").on('click', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault()
  let rowID = event.target.id
  if (rowID !== '') {
    $(`#foo,#${rowID}`)[1].remove()
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="foo">
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're selecting and removing both the table and the `tr` element - be careful with `,`! You should use `if (rowID) $(\`#${rowID}\`).remove()` instead.

Comment: Print out the value of “target.id”. Place this directly in the selector string and _show_ what it is. If this is a minimally question/problem, throw out the rest. If it’s not, examine and explain why. Also the title does not appear related or appropriately refined: two parameters were specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this Jquery doc https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$(document).on('click', "#foo .delete", function(event){
//do something here
})
```